# Removing Specific factor level from factor variable

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a data frame that has several variables that have 5 factor levels. I want to delete only one of those levels. First I assigned all instances of of that level to NA, and then used the `droplevels` command to get rid the empty levels.

However for one variable in my data frame one of the levels I don't want dropped has no observations in it. Is there a way to remove only a specific factor level, and not just the empty ones.

Here is a reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(var1=rep(letters[1:5],2),var2=rep(letters[5:1],2),var3=c("a","c","d","e","a","c","d","e","a","c"))
levels(df$var3)<-c("a","c","d","e","b")
```

This sets up a data frame like mine. Now I want to remove all instances of the level e, and then drop it as a possible level. I do this with the code below.

```
df2<-replace(df, df=="e",NA)
df2<-droplevels(df2)
```

The problem is when I use `droplevels` it drops level b from var3 also. I don't want to remove level b just level e from all of the variables. I have looked for a way to remove just a specific level, but have not found the answer. Can anyone show me how to remove just a specific factor level? What I would ideally like is a `droplevels` command that I can tell to just remove level e. Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str(
  as.data.frame(
    lapply(
      df2, 
      function(x) factor(as.character(x), levels=levels(x)[levels(x) != "e"])
) ) )
# 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ var1: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4 NA 1 2 3 4 NA
# $ var2: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": NA 4 3 2 1 NA 4 3 2 1
# $ var3: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","c","d","b": 1 2 3 NA 1 2 3 NA 1 2
```

Comment: I do not think the `as.character` is needed.

Comment: You're right, but I'm always super wary of factors all of a sudden behaving like their underlying numbers as opposed to their "values".  Clearly within the `factor` function expecting normal behavior is reasonable.

Comment: ``as.data.frame`` messes with variable names, but ``check.names = FALSE`` helps apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't just use `droplevels` on the factor column of interest:

```
df2$var2 <- droplevels(df2$var2)

> lapply(df2, levels)
$var1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$var2
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

$var3
[1] "a" "c" "d" "e" "b"
```

Explanation: `droplevels` is generic and there are both methods for factor and dataframe objects.

```
> methods(droplevels)
[1] droplevels.data.frame droplevels.factor
```

Comment: I think he wishes to drop the e level from all columns